# WPF Binding CheckBox IsChecked to ItemsSource DataModel Failing to See Model

Tags: wpf, checkbox, datatemplate

I have a WPF form using MVVM. Within that WPF window I have a reference to my `DataContext`:

```
DataContext="{x:Static modelView:MasterAutoSyncModelView.Instance}"
```

This `MasterAutoSyncModelView` contains an `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<AutoSyncJob> Jobs { get; set; }
```

In the window I have a `ListView` that contains a list of jobs. The job class looks like this:

```
public sealed class AutoSyncJob : ObservableModel
{
    private string _jobName;
    public string JobName
    {
        get { return _jobName; }
        set
        {
            _jobName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("JobName");
        }
    }

    private bool _isActive;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return _isActive; }
        set
        {
            _isActive = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsActive");
        }
    }
}
```

The list should have the CheckBoxes checked for a job that has its `IsActive` property set to true.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvJobs"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Height="628" Width="205"
          Margin="30,62,0,0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Jobs}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedJob, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridView.Columns>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Active" Width="50">
          <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>

        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding JobName}" Header="Job Name" Width="150">
        </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In the constructor for my test code I have two jobs. The first job has its `IsActive` set to True.  The second has it set to False.

When loading the window, both CheckBoxes are empty even though the `IsActive` is set to True.

Visual Studio complains that `IsActive` cannot be found. It's looking at my view model for the `IsActive` property, not the Job from the Jobs ItemsSource.

Rewriting the code to say

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Jobs/IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Removes this complaint, but the window still has no selected CheckBox on load.

How do you bind the `IsChecked` property to the `IsActive` boolean on the AutoSyncJob bound to that row from the Jobs ItemsSource so that it shows up checked or unchecked depending on the underlying model?

Second question: checking or unchecking the active box in the ListView does not trigger code in the model's setter, even though I have the mode set to TwoWay. Therefore if I uncheck or check the box, I would expect the model to have its `IsActive` property modified... but there is no communication.  I suspect this is because again the DataTemplate is not really bound to the model item.

Answer (score 1):

I have try your code and it works for me. Check whether your DataContex set properly.
I think you have not your DataContext, or it will be set later(before bindings have been checked)..
sorry for my english ;)

Comment: Works here, too.

Comment: The datacontext is working great for everything except for the checkbox itself.  

Would you mind posting your code if its working for you?  I'd like to see what's different.

Comment: All of my coworkers are backing away from my machine afraid of what it will do next.  (multiple coworkers saw it ignore the flag and leave it blank)

It now works just fine with no code changes.  Perhaps... it was a build?  I'm not sure.  Perhaps an exorcism of the machine with holy water.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a compiler issue.  Leaving it alone for a moment and coming back saw the issue resolve itself.  Same code posted above (no changes at all) it just decided to behave.

Sorry for the waste of time.